# JSONDecodeError when printing Flask server response status code

Tags: python, json, flask

I`m taking a course on Data Science and I have the following assignment on the Flask server. I have to send a post request with a json containing an integer. If this integer is less or equal to 10, the server should return the int number + 1, otherwise, it should return the string "too much". This training app consists of two simple files which I run locally in VS Code.

**server.py:**

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/hello')
def hello_func():
    name = request.args.get('name')
    return f'hello {name}!'

@app.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
def add():
    num = request.json.get('num')

    if num > 10:
        return 'too much', 400
    return jsonify({
        'result': num + 1
    })


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('localhost', 5000)
```

**client.py:**

```
import requests

if __name__ == '__main__':
   r = requests.post('http://localhost:5000/add', json={'num': 11})

   print(r.status_code, r.json())

   if r.status_code == 200:
      print(r.json()['result'])
   else:
      print(r.text)
```

Pay attention that in the **client.py** right after request line there is a print line that should print a response status code.

So, the issue is that when I set number in request less or equal to 10, the code works as expected. For num = 10 it prints out
200

11

However, when I set the num more than 10, let`s say 11, the client.py crashes on the line **print(r.status_code, r.json())**

**Here is the stack trace that I get:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Asolovei\MyDocs\Personal Docs\Programming\DataScience\Modules\PROD-4\PROD4\PROD5\client.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(r.status_code, r.json())
  File "C:\Users\Asolovei\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 910, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads    
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode    
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I`m running the code in the following way. First, I open one instance of VS Code and run server.py there. Then I open another VS Code instance and run client.py there while the first instance with server.py is still running.

Will appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: That's obvious, you don't return JSON if `num` is greater than 10, but trying to read JSON response in line which throw an error.

Comment: Yes, that`s clear :) Thank you!